# Measuring how much time requests take in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Suppose I've got a script to load a web page in PhantomJS.

```
var page = require('webpage').create()

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/hello.html'

page.open(url, function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  console.log(content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I'd like to know how much time it takes to load the page resources. So I modified my script like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create()

var dict = {}

page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    dict[req.url] = new Date().getTime()
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
  if (res.stage == "end") {
    dict[res.url] = new Date().getTime() - dict[res.url];
  }
};

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/hello.html'

page.open(url, function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(dict))
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Is there a better way to measure the request time?

Comment: If you use firebug, take a look at the console API : https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API you can get way more informations than a simple timer (console.time) with console.perform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're measuring time is totally fine, but a resource doesn't always have a unique URL. Multiple resources can have the same URL which would produce wrong results in your case. You should be using the `id` property of a request:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    dict[req.id] = new Date().getTime()
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
  if (res.stage == "end") {
    dict[res.id] = new Date().getTime() - dict[res.id];
  }
};
```

Note that there is the [netsniff.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netsniff.js) script in the [examples directory](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/tree/master/examples) which already does a lot of stuff for you.

Comment: Thank you ! I am using `id` + `url` as a key now.